# add and remove class if radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

I need to add class if second radio button is checked and remove class if radion button is unchecked. It doesn't work when radio button is unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#second').on('change',function(){
                    if ($('#second').attr("checked", "checked")){
                    $(".drag_and_drop").addClass('collapse');
                    } else {
                        $(".drag_and_drop").removeClass('collapse');
                    }
                });
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/34/

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: I added fiddle with code

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="test"]').on('change',function(){
        $(".drag_and_drop").toggleClass('collapse', this.checked && this.id == 'second');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vT4DB/)

- `$('#second').attr("checked", "checked")` is used to assign the value `checked` to the `checked` attibute, not to check whether the `checked` attribute  == 'checked' for that you need `$('#second').attr("checked") == "checked"`
- if you register the change event only to `second` then the change event will not get triggered when you select the `first` after selecting `second`. So register the change handler for the group of radio buttons and check whether the `second` one is checked
- You can use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) toggle a class assignment

Comment: I tried to use your example, but console says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @user3127896 the fiddle seems to be working fine, isn't it.... can you share how you have copied the code

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#second').on('change',function(){
        if ($('#second').is("checked")){
           $(".drag_and_drop").addClass('collapse');
        } else {
           $(".drag_and_drop").removeClass('collapse');
       }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $('input[name="test"]').on('change',function(){
     if ($('#second').is(":checked")){$(".drag_and_drop").addClass('collapse');} else {      $(".drag_and_drop").removeClass('collapse');
   }});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/37/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change your event selector. try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input:[name="test"]').on('change',function(){
                    if ($('#second').attr("checked")){
                       $(".drag_and_drop").addClass('collapse');

                    } else {
                        $(".drag_and_drop").removeClass('collapse');

                    }
                });
       });
```

[demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/38/)